# How to include date criteria in RavenDB Lucene query

Tags: c#, linq, lucene, ravendb

I have following index in RavenHQ

```
from doc in docs 
let Tag = doc["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"]
where  Tag != null && Tag=="Email"
select new { Tag, LastModified = (DateTime)doc["@metadata"]["LastModified"], DateAdded=doc.DateAdded };
```

also I did make the DateAdded Indexing as Analyzed. I want to write a Lucene query which includes ***less than date*** criteria in the where clause.

I tried following, but it didn't work.

```
Where("DateAdded: [NULL TO 2012-12-31").ToList()
```

What is the exact way in C# to provide the date in where clause.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to use Raven's API instead of constructing the query yourself:

```
var date = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<object>().WhereLessThan("LastModified", date);
```

If you *must* do it yourself, it's like this:

```
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<object>()
                .Where("LastModified: {NULL TO 2012-12-31T00:00:00.0000000Z}")
```

Raven uses the [Lucene Range Query Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Range%20Searches) paired with [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) datetime format to 7 decimal places, as is provided by the [Round Trip Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) that is obtained from with `dateTime.ToString("o")`.

Note that you said "less than" so I used the *exclusive* brackets `{ TO }`.  If you want "less than or equal" then you would use the *inclusive* brackets `[ TO ]` instead.

The query you provided in the question would have worked if you had included the ending `]` character.  However, it would not have been what you were looking for, since any `LastModified` entry with a time component would have fallen after the value you specified.

Also be aware that the `LastModified` metadata is stored as UTC.

Comment: Thanks Matt. You save my day.